# How to prep walls with cracked paint

Tags: painting, paint-removal

I'm in need of some advice. I am away to start redecorating my bathroom. My dad was originally going to do it for me but he is currently unwell so is no longer able to. I can't afford to pay someone so I figured I will give it a go, may not be perfect.
I moved into this place a few years ago and have held off doing the bathroom as there's alot of cracks in the paint so I figured it will be a big job. Above the door is the worst, if I can include a picture I will. Along the larger walls there are cracks but only visible if you look closely.

How and where do I start? I have my dad's tools, scrapers, sanding paper, he has given me electric ones too l, heat gun etc although if possible I would like to avoid using that especially in higher spots. How to I fix the walls with the finer cracks is it a different process than the larger ones? [image]

Comment: That look like it's caused by water or excess humidity.  There is also an area that appears to be damaged above the door frame.  You're going to want to remove all the cracked and peeling paint and fix all the damaged drywall.  After that, prime and paint.  You may want to add or upgrade the exhaust fan.

Comment: What is behind the paint? Is it drywall, plaster & lathe, some sort of wood paneling/planking? That may have an impact on what the fix is and how much repair you may have to/be able to do. Also, if it's possible for your dad to travel, he may be able to guide you even if he can't actually do the work.

Comment: I believe its dry wall, it is infact crumbling something I never noticed, it's like the previous occupants just painted over it. I ended up contacting my housing as I feel this job is a bit out of what I'm capable of. They came out quick and have offered to repair that wall and sort the cracks and paint it. This now just leaves the other walls which should be easier to sort as they have no issues other than cracked paint. Thank you for replying

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to really do this right is to sand/scrape off all the cracked paint. Painting over it will not hide the cracks and the old paint can continue to crack. In some instances, it might be easier to replace the drywall in the really bad areas.